# Backend tech stack for React/React Native App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, react-native, backend

I am planning on building an application that I want to deploy both on web and mobile. I would like the logic of the application to work offline for the mobile app, but when reconnected to the internet it should sync with the database so that it is the same as if they were doing things offline.

The application will have users with data that they can share with other users - changes do not need to be shown in real-time.

Does anyone have recommendations on what database provider would be helpful for this, and what backend tech stack I should use so that the offline syncing works?

Comment: We aren't a discussion forum and this question is too broad. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Where would you recommend I post this?

Comment: That's not my job to determine. I might suggest that you do some research rather than asking others to decide for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for either RealmDb or firebase. Depends on your needs.